# Angular Js geolocation module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-module

I am trying to implement geolocation in my angular app and found that with the help of geolocation module i can do it. i i installed this module in my app as described on the git hub. They have given a demo there 
See this [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/TM71LBh6ttYotOo6t7oX/preview) that displays your latitude/longitude.
But it seems that it is not working. please can you help me why this demo is not working.

Comment: the plunker demo is working fine in chrome...in which browser you are trying?

Comment: i am using chromium browser on ubuntu. and it is only asking me to allow to get the user location but not displaying location.

Comment: strange! I am able to see it working in chrome (build 32.0.1700.107) on my ubuntu machine.

Comment: you should check for any js error in browser console.

Comment: I am using Version 31.0.1650.63 Ubuntu 13.04. no error is coming in console.